# Registrar y anular la escucha de BroadcastReceiver en un fragmento de Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, broadcastreceiver

Quiero iniciar la detección de la conectividad con un `BroadcastReceiver` lo quiero hacer en un fragmento cuando este a pantalla.

¿En que métodos es el más optimo para registrar y en cual quitarlo pero contemplando lo siguiente?

Escenario donde la escucha debe estar activa:

- Al cargar el fragmento y ser visible inicie la escucha. `registerReceiver`
- Si el usuario cambia de fragmento, se para la escucha. `unregisterReceiver`
- Si el usuario cambia de app mientras la escucha este iniciada, pues que sigue en segundo plano.
- No es determinante que si por alguna razón el usuario no vuelve a la app y se paralice la escucha en un tiempo, pero que se cierra como debe ser, sin dejar problemas de memoria.

En este [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616654/registering-and-unregistering-broadcastreceiver-in-a-fragment) especifica que lo mejor manera es registrar la escucha en `onResume` y quitarla en `onPause`, pero obviamente eso no me deja que la escucha sigue, si el usuario minimiza la app.

Answer (score 0):

De momento lo solvento registrando al fragmento en `onResume()` y lo quito en `onDestroy()` pero no ser si siempre se acabará pasando por `onDestroy()`

Inicio la escucha en `onResume` del fragmento

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mIntentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);

    getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(mIntentFilter));

    super.onResume();
}
```

Y quito la escucha en `onDestroyView` del fragmento:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```